# Athena table - file's path

Tags: amazon-s3, path, powerbi, subdirectory, amazon-athena

I would like to create a table in athena by using the S3 bucket, but first I would want to know if  there is any way to bring the name of the subdirectory (source data of the files) as a new column in this table. If so, which is the syntax I should be using? If this is not possible, I would need at least the path of the file in that new column.

The subdirectory name is needed for a mapping in Power BI.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Find the Source File for an Athena Table Row](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/find-s3-source-file-athena-table-row/):

> - To find out which Amazon S3 file contains data that is returned by a specific row in an Athena table, run a `SELECT $path` query.
> - To find out which Athena table rows are associated with a specific Amazon S3 file, run a SELECT query with the `WHERE $path` condition.

From [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html#r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE_usage-pseudocolumns):

> By default, Amazon Redshift creates external tables with the pseudocolumns `$path` and `$size`. Select these columns to view the path to the data files on Amazon S3 and the size of the data files for each row returned by a query. The `$path` and `$size` column names must be delimited with double quotation marks. A `SELECT *` clause doesn't return the pseudocolumns. You must explicitly include the `$path` and `$size` column names in your query, as the following example shows:

```
select "$path", "$size"
from spectrum.sales_part
where saledate = '2008-12-01';
```